# Error installing RWeka / rJava on Ubuntu 12.04 / R 2.14.1

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the RWeka package for R 2.14.1 running on Ubuntu Linux 12.04.  I type:

```
install.packages("RWeka")
```

choose a mirror and it downloads.

Then I get these messages:

```
configure: error: Java Development Kit (JDK) is missing or not registered in R
Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf
as root to add Java support to R.

If you don't have root privileges, run
R CMD javareconf -e
to set all Java-related variables and then install rJava.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/rJava’
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘RWekajars’
* removing ‘/home/~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/RWekajars’
ERROR: dependencies ‘RWekajars’, ‘rJava’ are not available for package ‘RWeka’
* removing ‘/home/~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/RWeka’

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpZBJDM0/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("RWeka") :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("RWeka") :
  installation of package ‘RWekajars’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("RWeka") :
  installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status
```

So I quit and type:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

Let that run, then:

```
root@ubuntu:~# R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_24
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java compiler    : not present
Java headers gen.: 
Java archive tool: 
Java library path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
JNI linker flags : -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/amd64 -L/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/jni -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm
JNI cpp flags    : 

Updating Java configuration in /etc/R
Done.
```

Then I go back and start R and type install.packages("RWeka")

and get the same error message as before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: This looks like a problem that any user of R on Ubuntu could run in to, it's not really specific to sysadmins, I don't think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you might have the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installed, but not the JDK (Java Development Kit).

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Then try to install the package again.